# Using Def outside of Class to affect Class for short period of time

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I want to be able to rotate a Class on screen but only when it collides with another Class. As such, can I Def the rotation separately outside the Class so it will only come into affect for a specific time period before the Class goes back to its own internal Def functions?

Basically I want a race car to spin (rotate) when it hits an oil patch.

Comment: I think you're going to need to show some code for context. Having a method inside a class doesn't mean that you can't control when it executes. You need to call met) functions for them to run; regardless of where they are.

Comment: I think what you are talking about could be handled by polymorphism.  Take a look at that and other OOP principles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of this can be done within the object.  The approach I would take is to store the time a collision occurred, run the collision animation for a further set-time, then change back to normal view.  PyGame has a real-time millisecond clock accessible via the function [pygame.time.get_ticks()](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.get_ticks).

It's not a huge addition to your everyday sprite class.  First, given some animation-parameters, use PyGame to make a bunch of rotated copies of your image.  Then when a collision/spin is triggered, use the millisecond time elapsed (since the start of the event) to step through your animation.

```
import pygame
import random

# Window size
WINDOW_WIDTH    = 400
WINDOW_HEIGHT   = 400
WINDOW_SURFACE  = pygame.HWSURFACE|pygame.DOUBLEBUF|pygame.RESIZABLE

GRASS_GREEN = ( 3, 255,  54)

class CarSprite( pygame.sprite.Sprite ):
    SPIN_TIME  = 1950  # milliseconds spent spinning
    ANIM_DELAY = 50    # milliseconds per frame of animation

    def __init__( self, car_image, x, y ):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image       = car_image
        self.rect        = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = ( x, y )

        self.rotations      = [ self.image ]  
        self.spinning_since = 0  # not spinning (yet)
        self.makeRotations()     # create animation frames

    def makeRotations( self ):
        """ Pre-generate the rotated images for animating the spin """
        ROT_FRAMES = 36    # frames of rotation
        for i in range( ROT_FRAMES ):
            angle = i * ( 360 / ROT_FRAMES )
            rotated_image = pygame.transform.rotozoom(self.image, angle, 1)
            self.rotations.append( rotated_image )

    def spin( self ):
        """ Trigger a spinning action """
        if ( self.spinning_since == 0 ):
            self.spinning_since = pygame.time.get_ticks()  # Start spinning
        else:
            pass  # we're spinning already

    def update( self ):
        # If the car is spinning, set the frame of animation
        if ( self.spinning_since > 0 ):
            time_spinning = pygame.time.get_ticks() - self.spinning_since
            if ( time_spinning >= CarSprite.SPIN_TIME ):
                # Stop spinning, we've spun enough
                self.spinning_since = 0
                index = 0
            else:
                # Map the time to the appropriate animation
                index = int( time_spinning / CarSprite.ANIM_DELAY )
                index %= len( self.rotations )        # ensure it's a valid index

            # update the image, preserving the location about the centroid.
            cx, cy = self.rect.center             # preserve the centre of the image
            self.image = self.rotations[ index ]  # use the new image
            self.rect  = self.image.get_rect()
            self.rect.centerx = cx                # restore the old centre (bitmaps will be different sized)
            self.rect.centery = cy




### MAIN
pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode( ( WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT ), WINDOW_SURFACE )
pygame.display.set_caption("Collision Spin")


# Add some cars
car_image = pygame.image.load('car.png')
sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
for i in range(3):
    # Random position within the middle 80% of screen 
    pos_x = random.randrange( WINDOW_WIDTH//10, WINDOW_WIDTH-WINDOW_WIDTH//10 )
    pos_y = random.randrange( WINDOW_HEIGHT//10, WINDOW_HEIGHT-WINDOW_HEIGHT//10 )
    sprites.add( CarSprite( car_image, pos_x, pos_y ) ) 


clock = pygame.time.Clock()
done = False
while not done:
    # re-position all the cars
    sprites.update()

    # Handle user-input
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if ( event.type == pygame.QUIT ):
            done = True
        elif ( event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN ):
            # On mouse-click, tell *all* the cars they've collided
            for car in sprites:
                car.spin()

    # Movement keys
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    #if ( keys[pygame.K_UP] ):
    #    print("up")

    # Update the window, but not more than 60fps
    window.fill( GRASS_GREEN )
    sprites.draw( window )
    pygame.display.flip()

    # Clamp FPS
    clock.tick_busy_loop(60)


pygame.quit()
```

[image: example output video]

Vector Car Image taken from Vecteezy, used under [attribution](https://www.vecteezy.com/free-vector/car) licence. (Converted to a bitmap.)

[image: car.png]  `car.png`

Comment: Oh, this should store the previous image index, and then only re-set the image and rect when there has been a change.  I guess this is an optimisation left for the reader!

Comment: Think I may have figured it out by calling the car.spin() if pygame.sprite.spritecollide() happens

Comment: Kingsley.... thanks a bunch - i got it working perfectly and doing exactly what I want :)